# Disabling an (/dev/inputX) input device on Ubuntu(/Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, input, input-device

My story: I have a laptop with a touchscreen, which is a bit faulty. It jumps the cursor occasionally to one point of the screen. It's annoying, but I managed to find the correct input.

`/dev/input/mouse1` < this is the one I should permanently disable in Linux.

How can I do it on Ubuntu 11.04? (Saying the version because the correct answer may vary due to hal/evdev/whatevertheychangestuffdownto software.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding something like this to /etc/X11/xorg.conf should work:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier         "disable broken device"
   MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
   MatchProduct       "full product name from 'xinput list'"
   Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

For more matches see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Input_device_configuration#InputClasses .

Comment: Nice, gonna try it ASAP!

Comment: It's generally not recommended to match on specific device paths, as the ordering may change on reboot. `MatchIsTouchscreen "on"` possibly along with `MatchProduct "full product name from 'xinput list'"` would be somewhat better.

Comment: Strange. @Grawity - Your version works, the "MatchDevicePath" fails for some reason. Thanks, both of you!

Comment: Thanks @grawity, I changed according to to your suggestion.